# Does vscode use workspaceRoot or workspaceFolder?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw

I have been recently trying to use the MinGW gcc compiler with Code, and am getting some issues with Intellisense(not breaking, but I find it annoying).

I followed the documentation to edit the path for the c_cpp_properties.json file, but the error continues to pop up and I think I have also found contradictory information.

```
   {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
```

I looked on the github repo for the documentation and found someone had committed a change where ${workspaceRoot} was changed to workspaceFolder in the documentation. However, root seems to be the default for VS code, and I only updated to the new orange logo version this morning.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/commit/fa613d436a53bd9c5a21065cf5fa0f1b350d9bc6

So which is the correct way to get Intellisense working, Folder or Root?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_workspacefolder-in-launchjson-and-tasksjson.  They both should work but WSRoot is being deprecated because of the new multi-Folder abilities of VSCode.

Answer (score 12):

Turning @Marks comment into an answer: `${workspaceRoot}` is deprecated, `${workspaceFolder}` should be used instead: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

See also this description of variables: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

> ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code